# Argument 'indexController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

This has been asked before but it didn't answer my question. I am pretty new to angular and I am just putting things together at the moment. I am trying to get my factory to work inside my controller. However I keep getting the following error in my console:

```
Argument 'indexController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am broke the services and controller in different directories and I have added the service and controller `<script>` to the index.html file.

I am using IntelliJ and used its plug-in to create the boilerplate.

```
<body >
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>


  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div>

          <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"> </p>
          <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1> //this works just fine

  </div>

  <div ng-controller="indexController"> //doesn't appear
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="x in nameArray">
              {{x.name + ' is : '+x.age+' years old'}}
          </li>
      </ul>

  </div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('indexController', ['$scope', 'Contact', function($scope, Contact){

        var names = [
            {name:'Drew' , age: 30},
            {name:'Meike', age: 32},
            {name:'Garry', age:64}
        ];

        Contact.add(names);

    $scope.nameArray = Contact.get();



}]);
```

FactoryService:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .factory('Contact', function ContactFactory(){
        var personNames = [];
        return{

            add: function(name) {
                personNames.add(name);
            },

            get: function(){
                return personNames;
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't recreate the angular module `myApp` again inside FactoryService, when you create `myApp` module again it flushes out old registered component to that module. So when you register `FactoryService` it removes out old register component, here it removes `indexController` controller. And when `ng-controller` directive gets evaluated it searches for `indexController` controller inside module and throws an error

It should be

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('Contact', function ContactFactory(){
```

instead of

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .factory('Contact', function ContactFactory(){
```