# Google Chart Tools AngularJS Directive Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get Angular working with Google Charts via the Google Charts Angular Directive Module but can't seem to get it to work. I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

**Angular Code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['googlechart']);

myApp.factory("DataService", ["$http", function ($http){
    var getData = function(callback){
        var url = 'api-url-returns-json';
        $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }
    return {
            getDashboardData: getData
        }
}]);

myApp.controller("dashboardController", ["$scope", "DataService", "ClockProvider", function ($scope, DataService, ClockProvider){
    DataService.getDashboardData(function(data){
        $scope.dashboard = data;
    });
    var intervals = ["0", "30"];
    ClockProvider.run(intervals, function(){
        DataService.getDashboardData(function(data){
            $scope.dashboard = data;
        });
    });
}]);


angular.module("myApp", ["googlechart", "googlechart-docs"]).controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "BarChart";

    $scope.onions = [
        {v: "Onions"},
        {v: 3},
    ];

    $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions}
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]}
    ]};

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
            <script src="ng-google-chart.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="side front" ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
                <div google-chart chart="chartObject"">
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: where did you put your JS code?

Comment: I think you forgot to load your JS code in `<script>` tag :)

Comment: Seems kind of similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35350292/2435473), you have not instantiated and used angular module correctly, **OR** you are missed to add script reference on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are mistaking between declaring and calling the AngularJS module.

To declare a module, you use:

```
var myApp = angular.module("<Your app name>", [<Your dependencies>]);
```

However, to call the module (to create a `controller`, for example) just use:

```
//Notice that you don't put the [] in .module()
angular.module("myApp").controller
```

After fixing it, if the problem is still there, please check the reference. Remember to load all your necessary JS code, and in the correct order (load your dependencies before loading your app). For example:

```
<script src="Your dependencies path"></script>
<script src="Your Angular app path"></script>
```

Comment: I've done that but still didn't work :/ Is there any other info you want to know that could help?

Comment: When creating the `GenericChartCtrl`, try using `myApp.controller` instead of `angular.module().controller`. Remember to move the `googlechart-docs` dependency to the module declaration, so it should be `var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['googlechart', 'googlechart-docs']);`

Comment: I found out what it was! It was an error with the Google Chart example's data array, it was missing a comma after here: `{c: $scope.onions}`

Comment: LOL! Congratulations :D

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to define myApp 2 times:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['googlechart']);

...
angular.module("myApp", ["googlechart", "googlechart-docs"]).
```

if you want just to call the module then you should use:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['googlechart', 'googlechart-docs']);

...
angular.module("myApp").
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a module twice with *different*  dependencies.

At the top you have `var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['googlechart']);`

and a bit down you have `angular.module("myApp", ["googlechart", "googlechart-docs"])....`

You can however call `angular.module("myApp")` multiple times just fine, this will just give you a reference to your actual module.