# AngularJs dependency not working

Tags: angularjs

I've just installed the following package with bower:

https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner

The package is added successfully. I've also added:

```
<script src="bower_components/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.js"></script>
```

When I try to inject it like this:

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp',['angularSpinner']).controller('schoolController', schoolController);
```

It crashes and I receive the error:

```
Argument 'indexController' is not a function, got undefined
```

When I remove `['angularSpinner']` everything works again.

What should I do?

--EDIT--

**indexController**

```
angular.module('employeeApp').controller('indexController', indexController);

function indexController($location, authenticationFactory,constants)
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.setName = function()
    {
        return constants.firstname;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is indexController?

Comment: some where you have referenced the controller wrong, can you share the indexController code?

Comment: yea need more code also what is  `(function()
{`  leading to? need code before and after that

Comment: can you try 
`var indexController = function ($location, authenticationFactory,constants){....} angular.module('employeeApp').controller('indexController', indexController);`

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350274/argument-indexcontroller-is-not-a-function-got-undefined

Comment: the module is getting defined twice somewhere

Comment: Here is the [check list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797756/how-to-find-a-reason-angularjs-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefin/26797874#26797874) , what you should check whenever you got some error like this.

Comment: Thanks all! I declared it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in angular you create module for your app and there you specify the dependencies. and once you create controller or service you get the module by name and create controller\ service in that module.

```
//create module for app
 angular.module('employeeApp', [ /*add your dependencies here*/ ]);

//create controller\ service 
angular.module('employeeApp').controller(function(){
   //controller implementation
 });
```

what might happen is you may re initialize your app by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

for simplification you could store your angular module in a variable as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('employeeApp', ['angularSpinner']);
```

and define a controller like this:

```
app.controller('indexController',function(angularSpinner){
   //controller code here
});
```